# how to display the json array returned by php in an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My **Ajax** request looks like this

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        url: "new1.php",
       dataType: "json",
        data: { name: $('#name-typed').val()},
        success: function(response) {
        $('.cartcontainer').append(' <div class="cartproduct"><img src="images/deletesm.png" height="18" width="18" alt="deleteproduct" id="delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Product"/><span class="cartlist"><span><img src="images/wheatthumbnail.png" alt="ricethumbnail" class="cartcontent thmbnail" /></span><ul class="cartcontent"><li class="col"> </li><li class="col">'+ response.id + '</li><li class="crtqtymanuplator"><button>-</button><input type="text" id="crtcountholder" /><button>+</button></li></ul></span></div> ')
    }
  });
```

and my php file looks new1.php looks like this

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,"mydb");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM names";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$jsonData = array();

while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $jsonData['id'] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

what I want is to display  `id` returned as `json` array. How to do it?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: It says undefined in the place of '+ response.id +'

Comment: undefined what ?? can you please post it here ??

Comment: You could not have hidden that use of `response.id` more than this.

Answer (score 2):

use `$jsonData['id'][] = $array;` instead of `$jsonData['id'] = $array;`

also avoid printing extra things like "0 result" when you expect a JSON output.

Answer (score 2):

You send to server varibale $_POST['name'], and I assume you must receive one Id with this name... Try this code in new1.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT id FROM names WHERE `name` = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt  = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($array = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $jsonData = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: That was well spotted.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to deal with:

#### 1. Declare the content type as JSON

Add the following line in our PHP code before you echo the JSON:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

#### 2. Do not output anything else than JSON

This code is both invalid as conflicting with the content type:

```
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

You don't have an `if` matching with this `else` block, but maybe you tried to simplify the code for the question, not seeing it became invalid.

Anyway, remove this block completely. If you have an `if` testing the number of rows that matches this `else`, remove it as well.

The JSON output is enough.

#### 3. Output more than only last ID

Your query returns a list of IDs, but you currently only retain the last one. So change that code:

```
$jsonData = array('id' => array());
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $jsonData['id'][] = $array;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really intended to only get one particular ID, then change your SQL statement, so it only retrieves the ID of a particular user. @Aleksandr spotted this very well in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252315/how-to-display-the-json-array-returned-by-php-in-an-ajax-request/35252870#answer-35252677), so I will not repeat it here. Give him credit for that.

Still, even if you change your SQL to return only 1 record, the above change and suggestions below are still valid.

#### 4. Use template HTML instead of long HTML string

The HTML string in your callback is long and hard to read. Use a template tag inside your HTML, where you insert the HTML inside an invisible div, like this:

```
<div id="template1" style="display:none">
    <div class="cartproduct">
        <img src="images/deletesm.png" height="18" width="18"
             alt="deleteproduct" id="delete" data-toggle="tooltip" 
             data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Product"/>
        <span class="cartlist">
            <span>
                <img src="images/wheatthumbnail.png" alt="ricethumbnail"
                     class="cartcontent thmbnail" />
            </span>
            <ul class="cartcontent">
                <li class="col"></li>
                <li class="col">$1</li>
                <li class="crtqtymanuplator">
                    <button>-</button>
                    <input type="text" id="crtcountholder" />
                    <button>+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above HTML has *$1* to identify where the ID should be injected.
Then your JavaScript would retrieve the `innerHTML` of that invisible template element, inject the ID and append it. See code under next point.

#### 4. Process more than one ID

In the JavaScript code, you currently only deal with one ID. As with the above change the response will be an array, change the JavaScript success callback like this, making use of the template HTML.

Note that if ID can contain any character, you should make sure to escape it. But if ID is numerical, this step is not needed:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response.id !== undefined) {
        response.id.forEach(function (id) {
            // Escape id for use in HTML (Not needed if ID is numerical)
            id = $('<div/>').text(id).html();
            // Get template HTML, and inject id
            var html = $('#template1').html().replace(/$1/g, id);
            $('.cartcontainer').append(html);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('invalid response', response);
    }
}
```